# Assembly addressing mode and syntax

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I'm new to Assembly programming, and searched the web for tutorials and ebooks. I have found some confusing information about syntax in assembly language e.g. [in a tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_addressing_modes.htm) I read the following code:

```
MOV EBX, [MY_TABLE]     ; Effective Address of MY_TABLE in EBX
MOV [EBX], 110          ; MY_TABLE[0] = 110
```

And in a book I read:

```
mov ax, [Data] ; normal direct memory addressing of a wor
mov ebx, Data ; ebx = & Data
3 mov ax, [ebx] ; ax = *ebx
```

So when we `MOV` a variable enclosed in `[]` to a register like `EBX`, what value do we store in the register? The address or the actual value in that memory location?

Comment: The syntax depends on your assembler that you forgot to mention. However `[]` always means content of memory, so the first example is wrong. At least I am not aware of any assembler which would work differently.

Comment: Nasm assembler sorry I forgot about it the first excample is to tutorials.point site so better to read books written by professionals thanks for your answer

Comment: Or even better, the nasm manual [section 2.2.2 NASM Requires Square Brackets For Memory References](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.08/html/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.2.2)

Comment: @Jester Actually in many AT&T-syntax assemblers, `[]` denotes expression grouping (e.g. `mov $foo*[bar+baz],%eax`) instead of dereference.

Comment: In any assembler that accepts `mov [ebx], 110` to store into memory, `mov ebx, [my_table]` is gonna be memory reference too.

Comment: Are you sure the first example was `MOV`, and not `LEA`?

Comment: It's as you see it from a tutorial site copied-pasted

Comment: Wrong tutorials are the *worst*.  Avoid this one; who knows what other confusing mistakes you'll find.  For people who already know NASM, it's just a simple bug / mistake to find if you actually try the code, but for someone trying to *learn* NASM syntax it will be super confusing to have two conflicting things.  TutorialsPoint is well known as having lots of not-totally-correct information.

Answer (score 1):

From [the NASM manual](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.08/html/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.2.2):

> The rule is simply that any access to the *contents* of a memory location requires square brackets around the address, and any access to the *address* of a variable doesn't. So an instruction of the form `mov ax,foo` will *always* refer to a compile-time constant, whether it's an `EQU` or the address of a variable; and to access the *contents* of the variable `bar`, you must code `mov ax,[bar]`.

So

```
MOV EBX, [MY_TABLE]     ; Effective Address of MY_TABLE in EBX
```

is wrong: It does not set `EBX` to an address, but to the value stored at the `MY_TABLE` address.